# Getting error while fetching data from Gen2 datalake - Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature

Tags: c#, azure, azure-data-lake

I have below resources in Azure cloud infrastructure

1. Gen2 storage account
2. Azure function

Gen2 storage account has an `event` defined. Whenever a blob created, it will try to trigger an Azure function and sends the address of the new blob.

The azure function now tries to fetch the blob data using the address received from Gen2 storage using SAS token which is defined in the storage account.

I am getting below error

> Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of the Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature

I tried to regenerate the token, but no luck

My reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/read

This is how I generated the token

[image]

I also tried both "?" and "&" as the starting character of the token. However, no luck.

I also tried both `HTTP` and `HTTPS` during token generation.

Updated sample SAS (**obfuscated SIG portion information**)

> &sv=2019-10-10&ss=mfat&srt=pco&sp=kwdmacusx&se=2099-05-10T14:36:06Z&st=2020-05-10T06:36:06Z&spr=https,http&sig=*******%2CCvt7B24SM****Ikde%******************%3A

**Observation** - "Get shared access signature" is disabled in storage explorer for this storage account.

[image]

Comment: How are you generating the SAS token. Please edit your question and include the code.

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS  Updated the question.

Comment: Thanks. Can you also share how are you using the SAS URL? Also share how your SAS URL looks like (obfuscate the account name and sig portion in your SAS URL).

Comment: shared obfuscated data.

Comment: Could you please provide the code of how you get the blob data with sas token?

Comment: I got a response from Microsoft. It's an issue in their service. they are working on it fixing it.

Comment: @kudlatiger Could you share the workaround as an answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Comment: Fix seems to be released from MICROSOFT. I shall test and keep you posted.